# How to pass All Arrays in Google Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a HTML File that upload a TSV File and display it in console as an array. here is the code.

```js
    document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

    var file = this.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // Entire file
    console.log(this.result);

    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        // By tabs
        var tabs = lines[line].split('\\t');
        for(var tab = 0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){    
                console.log(tabs[tab]);
        }   
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

```html
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

now here is my `code.gs`

```
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  return html;
}
```

My question is how can I pass the array from the html file to `code.gs`? maybe a sample `Logger.log` will be okay form me. My target here is to upload that array in google sheet. TYSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following modification? When it sends the values on html to GAS, you can achieve this using [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

In this modifed sample, the array is sent to `work()` on GAS, and the array data is imported to Spreadsheet.

### Modified Script :

#### index.html

```
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){
  var file = this.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // Entire file
    console.log(this.result);
    // By lines
    var ar = []; // <--- added
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      // By tabs
      var tabs = lines[line].split('\t'); // <--- modified from '\\t' to '/t'
      for(var tab = 0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){    
        console.log(tabs[tab]);
      }
      ar.push(tabs); // <--- added
    }
    google.script.run.work(ar); // <--- added
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

#### code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  return html;
}

function work(res){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange(1,1,res.length,res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

### Input

```
a1  b1  c1
a2  b2  c2
a3  b3  c3
```

### Output

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: TYSM for the help sir. I wonder sir. for additional question is it posible to set default folder location where i need to get the file? no more file upload for example `C:\XX\XXX\YourGreatTanaike.txt` like that

Comment: @paul pagente In my experience, I remember that when it selects files at ``<input type="file"  >``, the default path cannot be set because of the security. So I don't know how to set the default path to ``<input type="file"  >``. If this had already been modified, I'm sorry.

Comment: yah thats true ive been googling for almost an hour to find the answer to that question or maybe some workaround. anyways sir TYSSSSSSSSM its a great honor working with you :) approved and +1

Comment: @Tanakie no sir,no need to say sorry. atleast 80% of my problem has been solved(Thanks to you) the only problem is that i need to set a code that will upload a file from a specified location without using file upload. I dont want to create another post with that question because surely it will be downvoted.

Comment: Actually no sir. But I have a question. the initial rows of a sheet is 1000? I started to upload a 200,000 rows then it gives me an error that no more rows to be inserted something like that. the error occurs when the row is more than 1000

Comment: @paul pagente The number of rows in initial sheet is 1000. But I don't know about your situation. So can you submit the question with the detail information as a new question? I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: Sir Please check this one. -->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727458/adjust-the-no-of-rows-in-sheet-based-on-the-number-of-arrays