# adjust the no of rows in sheet based on the number of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

With a help from a friend,I have a code that uploads a txt file and here it is.

```js
 document.getElementById('file').onchange = function(){

    var file = this.files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
    // Entire file
    console.log(this.result);

    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
        // By tabs
        var tabs = lines[line].split('\\t');
        for(var tab = 0; tab < tabs.length; tab++){    
                console.log(tabs[tab]);
        }   
    }
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

and this is my `code.gs`

```
function doGet(e){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
  return html;
}

function work(res){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange(1,1,res.length,res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

The output of this code is :

1. Upload a Tab Seperated File
2. Convert that file into array
3. Insert that array in Google Sheet

Actually the code is working but there is a problem. the google sheet has an initial of 1000 rows and I encountered a scenario where I will upload a file that contains million rows. How can I adjust the no. of rows in sheet based on the number of arrays.

Comment: The maximum number of cells which can be used at Spreadsheet is 2,000,000. The detail information is https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en&vid=0-1349183067517-1502948992898 The spreadsheet has 1000 rows and 26 columns as the default. This is 26,000 cells. So for example, if you import 1,000,000 rows, the total cells are 26,000,000. It's over the limitations and an error occurs. If your data is only 2 columns and 1,000,000 rows, at first, you can import the data by removing unused columns.

Comment: well i think the best approach here is to find a way to adjust how many column and rows are needed. for example if the array is `[xx,xx,xx,xx]` then the columns must be 4 only. I mean adjust the number of rows and column based on array.